Setup reverse proxy to route requests to two alb's
I have two alb's
alb1 - created by infra team manually to serve all the requests from asp.net MVC application
alb2 - created by Kubernetes automatically to serve all the pages from the next.js app
now I want to serve both the old and new pages(next.js) in a single domain.
something like this.
abc.com/oldpage - - serve from alb1
abc.com/* - serve from alb1
abc.com/newpage - serve from alb2

I tried few solutions like using the old alb in kubernetes to add more listener rules by path
but I am getting an error.
Can someone help what is the best approach to do something like this?

Domain attached to LB on DNS level. You can't manage the path by DNS.
Could you share your error? And how did you add a listener's rule to LB?

I don’t want to add the listener rules manually in the alb1 as I mentioned in the post , alb2 and it’s target groups are getting created by k8s .

Is it AWS ingres or Nginx-Ingres? What target on your DNS record for abc.com domain? Do you use CloudFront?

It’s a Aws ingress

What error did you get when adding more listener rules?

It’s not an error, we need to add listener rules manually by adding the k8s nodes as targets in the alb1.i am thinking if we do that we are not fully leveraging k8s features. We are using some other DNS tool to point the domain to the alb1.

We are using some other DNS tool to point the domain to the alb1 Does this tool support path routing? Like the CloudFront https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern?

No, it won't support path-based routing from DNS.
I tried 2 options

Add a DNS entry to point abc.com to alb1 and add more listener rules to route traffic to next.js app based on the path.this approach works but I need to add listener rules manually in alb1.
Created a separate nginx deployment and alb and updated the domain to point to new nginx alb and inside nginx config added location based rules
e.g /location /newpage point to alb2 and /location oldpage point to alb1
issue with 2nd approach is I am getting too many redirects issue when I hit the alb1 from nginx alb.


Ok. I got it. You can have only one LB for one domain. But you can create a new subdomain for old service. But unfortunately, AWS ingress doesn't support External Service. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/3505 . But if you will use Nginx-ingress + NLB it can be done like External Service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
